# React-Native and MongoDB simple connection

Tags: mongodb, react-native

Do someone have tutorials on how to connect React-Native and MongoDB? Since I'm learning this technologies I wanted to make some small examples.
I wanted to do a simple form and save those inputs on my Mongo Collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this video as exemple: https://youtu.be/pSSF1oZAA5I 
Also you can use mangodb lib in nodejs in this link
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb.asp

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not have your React Native frontend communicate directly to the database but rather the frontend sends requests to a backend server that interacts with the database and returns data to the frontend. This is mostly because if you put your connection string / secret api access keys to your database in your frontend then anyone could easily extract it and do malicious things to your database.

This explains then why there is no "frontend javascript" in the [list of MongoDB drivers](https://api.mongodb.com).

There are many tutorials out there about using the NodeJs MongoDB driver. Here are a few:

- https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html
- https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/
- https://www.guru99.com/node-js-mongodb.html
- https://dzone.com/articles/crud-operations-on-mongodb-thru-nodejs
- http://zetcode.com/javascript/mongodb/
- https://flaviocopes.com/node-mongodb/